# Are these actual calcutated numbers?

Tags: support, questions

When I look at [link to aerea 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260?phase=beta) I see some numbers which ate obviously actual e.g. days in beta and currently 26 users with 200+ rep. 
But questions per day shows 7.9 and that seems to be too low.

Does this page actually tell how well our beta devellops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes but there is some buffering and it really isnt a useful set of metrics till public beta